# enabling CORS Google Cloud Function (Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cors, flask-cors

Can use you [`flask_cors`](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Cors/) in Google Cloud Functions?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
```

Locally this `flask_cors` package works but when deployed onto Cloud Functions it does not.

I have tried many different ways, as GCP has suggested https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http
but I am still getting that CORS error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 12):

No, the `app` variable is not available in Cloud Functions.

Instead you can manually handle CORS:

```
def cors_enabled_function(request):
    # For more information about CORS and CORS preflight requests, see
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request
    # for more information.

    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }

    return ('Hello World!', 200, headers)
```

See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests for more details.

Comment: thanks! How would I implement this into my cloud function though? Do I call this function within my function that I actually want to run?
`def predict(request): 
  cors_enabled_function(request)
# do the rest of my function 
`

Comment: The snippet here _is_ a Cloud Function (note that it takes a `request` parameter). You should add these lines at the top of your function.

Comment: @DustinIngram, does this solution work if the function required authentication? I mean, must the OPTIONS request add the security header or not?

Comment: hi @mdev, I have the same problem as you. How to I integrate this to my cloud function? I get the request, but how to I add this to the request? Did you figure this out?

Comment: That docs example has never worked for me. Not in my apps or in JSFiddle. I think it's missing something.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `flask` already then the easiest way is to use `flask-cors`

https://github.com/corydolphin/flask-cors

Decorate your cloud function like below and you're done.

```py
from flask_cors import cross_origin

@cross_origin()
@json
def fun_function(request):
    # enter code here
```

Or you can add as much functionality as you need as shown below.

```py
from flask_cors import cross_origin

@cross_origin(allowed_methods=['POST'])
@json
def fun_function(request):
    # enter code here
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `APP` in cloud functions. You can set the CORS headers as stated in [google cloud documentations](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests) and return your JSON as how you write in Flask.

The example below function called `hello_world` which is used for a post request. It return the status and headers of the `CORS`.

```
from flask import jsonify

def hello_world(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }

   if request_json and 'labels' in request_json:
        # THIS IS THE PLACE YOU WRITE YOUR CODE.
        # AWLAYS RETURN WITH THE HEADERS AND STATUS
        return (jsonify({"ok": "Great Day 2"}), 200, headers)
```

Answer (score 2):

@mdev, I had a similar issue and solved it by adding the CORS headers for the preflighted request at the beginning of my cors_enabled_function (as Dustin Ingram suggests); the CORS headers for the main request I left for the end of my function (this way including the response in the return statement, be it JSON, text, etc). In other words, I put my main function code in between the preflighted and main CORS requests.

Comment: Sometimes a hero as to live without credits. This did the trick for me! Should be explained more clear in all documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make a `Post request` to your `google cloud function` from the front end and face an issue with `CORS`. The Following template must work. It worked for me...

```
#import all required packages
import json

def function_name(request):
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',  # Allow your function to be called from any domain
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',  # POST or any method type you need to call
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type', 
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
        }
        return ('', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for main requests
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }

    # Your code logic goes here

    # Return your response
    return (json.dumps({'status': 'success'}), 200, headers)
```

If you also want to handle Auth in function after a preflight request refer to this discussion: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/reactfire/discussions/483

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase Python Cloud Functions, it can be done like this:

```
from firebase_functions import https_fn, options

cors_settings = options.CorsOptions(cors_methods=["*"], cors_origins=["*"])

@https_fn.on_request(cors=cors_settings)
def cors_enabled_function(request):
    return https_fn.Response("cors enabled!")
```